# pop up con datos ya existentes en mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html

Lo que necesita mi pagina es que al momento de modificar un dato bajo una ID, se abra un pop up con datos que tengo en la db, intente buscar pero no encontré algo que me ayude, el codigo que tengo hasta ahora me sirve pero solamente para insertar

```
 <script> function abrir() { 
window.open("ingreso.php","recogedor","width=500,height=550, top=50,left=50); 
return false; }
```

y hacer un href hace que se abra otra ventana

```
 href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pasa el id a la funcion abrir y desde alli lo pasas como parámetro

```
<script> 
    function abrirModificar(id) { 
        window.open("modificar.php?id="+id,"recogedor","width=500,height=550, top=50,left=50); 
        return false; 
    } 
</script>
```

En el elemento que lanze el abrirModificar solo tienes que pasar el id

```
onclick="abrirModificar("+$row['id']+");"
```