# Mostrar información en un pop up en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup

Me gustaría hacer una cosa. El tema seria que al dar a un botón la persona pudiera ver los fichajes del empleado en una ventana pequeña, pero no consigo meterlo en el código php,html. He probado con JavaScrip , pero nada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Empleados </title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("css/mycss.css");
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
fun

</head>
<body>
<div class="todo">
<div id="cabecera">
   <img src="images/swirl.png" width="1188" id="img1">
</div>

  <div id="contenido">
   <table style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
    <thead>
   <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Rango</th>
     <th>Grupo</th>
    </thead>
    <?php

    $conexion = new mysqli("xxxx","xxxxx","xxxx", "xxxx");
    $sentencia="SELECT * FROM `mysql_auth` WHERE grupo = 'badu' OR grupo = 'jefebadu' ORDER BY FIELD(rango,'Jefa','Jefe','Experimentado','Aprendiz')";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($sentencia) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
     while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>"; echo $fila['empleado']; echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>"; echo $fila['rango']; echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>"; echo $fila['grupo']; echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>  <a href='index.php?no=".$fila['id']."&empleado=".$fila['empleado']."&rango=".$fila['rango']."&grupo=".$fila['grupo']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Modificar</button> </a> </td>";
      echo "<td> <a href='eliminar_prod.php?no=".$fila['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button></a> </td>";
      echo "<td> <button type='button' onclick='abrirModificar("+$fila['empleado']+")' class='btn btn-success'>Ver Fichajes</button></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
   </table>
   <script> 
    function abrirModificar(id) 
    { 
        window.open("modificar.php?id="+id,"recogedor","width=500,height=550, top=50,left=50);
        return false; 
    } 
 </script>
  </div>


<?php

$id = $_GET['no'];
$empleado = $_GET['empleado'];
$rango = $_GET['rango'];
$grupo = $_GET['grupo'];
?>
<table width="50%" >
<tbody>
<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">
 <div class="todo">
   <div id="contenido">
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
    <span> <h1>Modificar Empleados</h1> </span>
    <br>
  <form action="modif_datos.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$id"?>">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="empleado" name="empleado"; value="<?php echo "$empleado" ?>" ><br>
    <label>Rango: </label>
    <input type="text" id="rango" name="rango" value="<?php echo "$rango" ?>"><br>
    <label>Pass: </label>
    <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass"><br>
    <label>Grupo: </label>
    <select id="grupo" name="grupo">
     <option>badu</option>
     <option>jefedadu</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</td>
<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">
 <div class="todo">
   <div id="contenido">
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
    <span> <h1>Nuevos Empleados</h1> </span>
    <br>
  <form action="nuevo_datos.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="empleado" name="empleado"><br>
    <label>Rango: </label>
    <input type="text" id="rango" name="rango"><br>
    <label>Pass: </label>
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
   </form>
  </div>


 </div>
 
</td>
 </tbody>
</table>   
  <div id="footer">
      <img src="images/swirl2.png" id="img2">
    </div>

</div>

</div>


<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema esta en esta parte , que no consigo solucionar, he visto guías pero no he podido entenderlas correctamente

```html
          echo "<td> <button type='button' onclick='abrirModificar("+$fila['empleado']+")' class='btn btn-success'>Ver Fichajes</button></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      ?>
       </table>
       <script> 
        function abrirModificar(id) 
        { 
            window.open("pop.php?em="+id,"recogedor","width=500,height=550, top=50,left=50);
            return false; 
        } 
     </script>
```

Como podria solucionarlo? El popup solo mostrara la tabla de la basa de datos, cogiendo la información de un GET

Este ultimo intente obtuve la información de [pop up con datos ya existentes en mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175569/pop-up-con-datos-ya-existentes-en-mysql)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo enviar el id a una modal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363555/como-puedo-enviar-el-id-a-una-modal)

Comment: Le eche un ojo, pero no entiendo como funciona el modal, no se como implementarlo en el mismo código

Comment: ¿Tienes todo ese código en un solo archivo?

Comment: Si. Lo unico, que no se ve , seria el codigo del pop.php. Simplemente seria coger la variable del $_get y enviarla la consulta mysql